# Example of a ring $R$ in which $a^2=0 \implies a \in J(R)$ but $N(R) \nsubseteq J(R)$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $R$ be a non-commutative ring. Suppose $N(R)$ and $J(R)$ respectively denote the set of nilpotent elements and the Jacobson radical of $R$.

Consider the following statements:

(1) $N(R) \subseteq J(R)$,

(2) $a^2=0 \implies a \in J(R)$.

Clearly, $(1) \implies (2)$.

> Does $(2) \implies (1)$ ?

The answer to this question should be negative. Please help us to find a suitable counter example.

**P.S. This is an open question. If somebody can solve it then he/she will be duly credited.**

Comment: Do you mean to quantify "For all $a\in R$, $a^2=0\implies a\in J(R)$?

Comment: Nil radical is always contained in Jacobson radical. Given $a\in R$, $a^2=0$ implies $a$ is in the nil radical so it is in the Jacobson radical. What is your question

Comment: @arnab Are you assuming a commutative ring?

Comment: @rschwieb We can at least wait for users response. I do not see why it is an emergency to mark it as a duplicate.

Comment: I am assuming $R$ to be noncommutative. @rschwieb

Comment: I can't say I've seen anyone control where elements of a particular nilpotency index land. Seems hard... unless someone finds a clever example. It also implies that every nilpotent element has a power in $J(R)$...